# "A snap on the back" vs. "a snap at the back"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> I have the hat which has a snap *on/at* the back of the hat.

Which preposition to use here?

This is the sort of thing the sentence refers to:
[image: Baseball cap with snap-fix strap at the back]

Comment: *It* is not a preposition.

Comment: I am so numpty, sorry I have edited the questions. It was supposed to be at instead of it, sorry.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether *it* should have been *at* or *in*. Actually any of *on/at/in* can be used; but normally you would not repeat "the hat" at the end of the sentence. Just use "...the back of it," as *it* refers back to *hat*.

Comment: Oh, wait, so I can use in the back? Doesn't it supposed to be between on or at, since the snap isn't really inside the hat? Another thing, assume there is a photo of 3 chaps. It is okay to say the lad on/in/at the middle?

Comment: The phrase is always "in the middle" for a group. As for the hat, it would help to have a picture of what you're talking about. Descriptive prepositions like this do depend on precisely what is being described.

Comment: Oh really? In the middle is correct? Even though when the photo is on the internet? Because there is a photo on facebook and some commented "on the middle" and then i have to convinced myself that i was wrong to say "in the middle"

Comment: Please keep to one question at once. Shall we deal with the one in hand? Can you edit it to include a picture of the sort of hat you're talking about?

Comment: "You need at least 10 reputation to post images." :( please go here [http://bit.ly/13UdcI9]

Comment: This is an *adjustable baseball cap (with [snaps][velcro][a slider])*.  If it didn't have the adjustable part, it would be a *fitted baseball cap*.  I don't know that I would describe the snaps unless it is likely that the intended reader has never seen a baseball cap.  "*I have the adjustable baseball cap with snaps.*"

Comment: Yeah, Oh okay. And I just knew that we say on the right and left, but in the middle. Oh, I am a numpty person.

Comment: I didn't see this clarified for you so here's this..."in the back" doesn't have to mean "inside the back".  It's one of the goofy idioms that is not exactly intuitive.  For example, if I said, "Let's meet at the abandoned warehouse, in the back".  While it *could* mean inside, in the back, it could also mean at the back of the building.  So . . . if someone asks where are the snaps on the hat, you could say "in the back". :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez While not disputing what Kristina says, I think I should point out that (if I understand correctly) she's discussing American usage. In British usage, I don't think it would be common for "in the back" to be used in the ways described: "in the back" would tend to mean "inside the back".

Comment: @TrevorD, sorry, yes, American English usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prepositions 'at' and 'on' can both serve as ['prepositions of place'](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-place.htm) and the choice depends on whether you are trying to describe where on the hat (directionally) the snap is, in which case 'at' would be the appropriate word, or the surface on which the snap resides (in which case 'on' would be more appropriate).

If you're primary concern here is how to refer to these hats, they are often referred to as "snapback" hats or "snapbacks", and are marketed as such (e.g. the NBA has a whole line of ['Snapback Hats'](http://store.nba.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=3131240))

Comment: In British usage, I would say "at the back". Incidentally, I didn't even understand the reference to "snap" without enlarging the picture and studying it carefully. We certainly wouldn't call these just "snap(s)", although we might call them "snap fasteners". And (at least to this Brit) "snapback(s)" is a whole new language - and I didn't know it's a baseball hat until I read it in one of the comments!

Comment: @TrevorD sorry, forgot to mention that this is very much my American-English insight! It must be seeping into the British (slang) lexicon somehow as I've heard 'snapback' and 'chav' used in the same sentence and 'chav' (the word) doesn't really seem to have made it to this side of the pond.

Comment: Isn't 'Chav' often used to describe aggressive teenagers, of white working class background, who repeatedly engage in anti-social behaviour ?

Comment: I actually knew it was called snapback. I just use the snap to describe my confusion, sorry. And thanks for the explanation. 'At' means directionally, and On means the surface. I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: @Edward Octavianus Pakpahan Yep, you've got *chav* right. Snapbacks have, apparently, made it into the chav style repertoire- resulting in their co-mingling in a sentence! Though, who knows how preposition use fits into that world...